Cannot play a resource that has already ended. / Could not extract functions
I'm getting the "Cannot play a resource that has already ended." when I try playing music with this current code:
https://sourceb.in/yaQ12o8KPT
-
It makes the bot crashes with that error message (Cannot play a resource that has already ended.).
While I was trying to get the error message again to open an issue, it crashed with this long message (probably the "console.log(resource)").
Not sure how I got it tho.
The error:
https://sourceb.in/bHiAd1Rfcy
-
Also just to add a last thing, I'm new to @discordjs/voice or anything related to discord.js voice coding, so I'm sorry if I can not give much information.
I got it working playing music saved on my pc as a file, but can not get it to play music from a link on the internet what so ever, if you please take your time to read and help me out, that would be very helpful!

I tested out an idea which resulted in this error: https://sourceb.in/sAvJkoVOBj
My new code: https://sourceb.in/KHaSwabSRD

Another error when I changed the url, apparently the ^^^ youtube link music was "broken", when i changed, this error popped up: https://sourceb.in/3clmIevGFA
